# Loop through elements in scope and match on type via Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to limit the search scope that the user can define in their config, and then loop through every element in it to match on only heading elements.

I currently have the `scope` limited:

```js
const scope = document.getElementById( 'main' );
```

Which returns this in the `console.log(scope);`

[image]

I've been trying to find a way to loop through the elements, but everything I try doesn't work.

I've tried:

```js
const elements = scope.getElementsByTagName('*');
```

But that returns the HTML as a string.

I've tried doing a `for( var i in scope ) OR for( var i in elements )` but that returns a whole bunch of looped data that doesn't seem right.

The example DOM code is obviously not exhaustive, but the aim is to get every H1-6 in their order and then be able to edit the `innerText` or edit the element to add anther tag.

Comment: Is jquery an option?

Comment: thank you - i have to use vanilla since it’s an extension to another framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vanilla JS:

```
const scope = document.getElementById('main');

const headers = document.querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6');

headers.forEach(h => {
    h.innerText = 'modified text';
});
```

If you can use jQuery, try this:

```
var scope = $('#main');

scope.children(':header').each(function(index) {
    $(this).text('modified text');
});
```

Comment: any way to do this with just javascript? seems very clean

Comment: sure, I'll add it to my answer